# How to get bigger image in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento rwd theme with a extension - for selected product widget.

The problem I am not able to increase the size of the image.
the relevant code is like this:

```
<?php


$products = $this->getProductCollection();?>
<?php if ($products && $products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-products selected-products">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->getBlockName() ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="products-block">
            <?php foreach ($products->getItems() as $product): ?>
                <?php /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */ ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <a class="product-image"
                       href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                       title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                        <img
                            src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(300,400) ?>"
                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>

                    <div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                               title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true) ?>)">
                                <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($product, $product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <?php if ($product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                            <div class="product-price">
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product, true) ?>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button"
                                    title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"
                                    class="button btn-cart"
                                    onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')">
                                <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
                            </button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set the resize to 300x400, but I am getting it - 118x157

The website link for reference -
[Change your Belief for Success](http://changeyourbeliefforsuccess.com)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constrainOnly to true on the image helper before resizing:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($product, 'image')
    ->constrainOnly(true)
    ->resize(300,400);
```

From the PHPDoc of the method:

```
Guarantee, that image picture will not be bigger, than it was.
Applicable before calling resize()
It is false by default
```

Comment: It is not making bigger. I have added the `->constrainOnly(true)`.

Comment: Then try false instead, maybe the default value gets overwritten somewhere and you have to set it to false manually.